# The type System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString may not be used in this context

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

what does the meaning of following error ?

> "The type System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString may not be used in this
>   context. To use System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString as a parameter, return
>   type, or member of a class or struct, the parameter, return type, or
>   member must be declared as type System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString (it
>   cannot be object). Objects of type System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString may
>   not be used in un-typed collections, such as ArrayLists." "

here is my code

```
[Serializable]
public class ReportSource{
 [XmlArray]
 public List<SqlParameter> Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

please help

Thanks

Comment: where is the error thrown?

Comment: error throw when it try to serialize Parameters property.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `SQLParameter` is not XML-serializable, or at least that it's not serializable when its `Value` property (which is of type `Object`) contains an `SqlString`.